# Can a semantic query type support advanced query forms?

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search, semantic-search

I am working with Azure Cognitive Search and while going through its documentation I came across the advanced query forms like fielded search, fuzzy search, proximity search and many more, but all of these advanced forms were supported by queryType = full

Are these advanced query forms also supported by queryType = semantic?

Here is the documentation link I am referring to: [Azure Cognitive Search Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-overview)

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, that the full query type is not supported when doing a semantic search query, however, semantic does have built into the models an ability to handle fuzziness of words. This is because semantic uses the family of models that powers Bing.com web searches which accommodates for this fuzziness of words. I will concede that there is value in enabling fuzzy even for semantic because it can help to get better candidate content for semantic to re-rank, and is an area we are currently investigating to make this first (L1) stage more effective.